# How do I disable all radio buttons after select?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm trying to disable all radio buttons with a specific name after one has been checked/selected.

This is my try:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("question0");
for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  radios[i].onclick = showResult;
}

function showResult() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is that all radio buttons will now be disabled, even those who have the name `question1`.

And how do I do this to a function for every question? So if I choose one option at `question1` I can't change my answer but can still choose at `question2`.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, how you're disabling the radio buttons and how you're handling `question1` etc.

Comment: show detail of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the whole set of radio buttons by targeting them according to `name` when one of them is clicked.

See this working example:

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  radios[i].onclick = function() {
    showResult(this.name);
  }
}

function showResult(name) {
  var x = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
Question 0:
<input type="radio" name="question0" val="answer1">
<input type="radio" name="question0" val="answer2">
<input type="radio" name="question0" val="answer3">

<br /> Question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" val="answer1">
<input type="radio" name="question1" val="answer2">
<input type="radio" name="question1" val="answer3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the same class of all radio button which you want to disable and on class click event you can add attribute disabled

Are you understand?

Answer (score 0):

`showResult` should just disable the buttons with the same name as the button that was clicked.

```
  function showResult() {
     var x = document.getElementsByName(this.name);
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].disabled = true;
     }
  }
```

Make this the click handler of all the radio buttons:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")).forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", showResult);
});
```

Comment: Okey so that works fine for the first one, but how do i use this for my all 5 questions? The smart way..

Comment: It should work for all the questions. `this.name` is the name of the button they clicked on, so it will disable all the other buttons with the same name. But buttons with different names will not be disabled until you click on one of them.